# compiling bibtex outputs only numbers

Tags: bibtex

I am fairly new to latex, but I have already written a few papers using it on my computer. I am now working on a new computer. I made a regular .bib file and used `~\cite` as usual. I compiled it using texworks, but all I got in the end of the pdf document, where the `\bibliography` tag was at the latex file, is just a list of numbers without the actual text of the authors' name, title etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This can happen when there are syntax errors in the `.bib` file. You should look at the `.blg` file produced when running BibTeX.

Comment: @egreg - thanks! that was it! I had comments (`% comment`) in places where it wasn't legal in the `bib` file. If you'd like, you should write this comment as an answer to get full credit :) if not I'll do it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "only numbers" in the bibliography is a typical effect of having syntax errors in the `.bib` file. A check in the `.blg` file produced when running BibTeX usually sheds light on the business.

In particular, `%` character inside bibliographic entries are *not* comments (they are outside them, for instance at the beginning of the file). In order to comment a field, say `note`, the best strategy os to change its name; for instance, with

```
Xnote={Some note we don't want to appear, but we like to have in the file},
```

the `Xnote` field will be ignored. Removing the `X` would turn the field into a good one.